# Getting corrupted jpg files using TCP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

i'm working with C#, i am connected to a server using one Async TCP socket, the purpose is that the server sends me 5 image files every second.

I took one tutorial about how to make the socket connection, so i think the problem is on the ReadCallBack function. Some jpgs arrive fine but other in a format that windows can't open and i can't understand why.

EDIT: After read different posts and look for more information, i changed completely the way to make that and finally is working fine, if somebody is in the same case, here is how i did it:

```
StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
Socket handler = state.workSocket;

int cont = 0;

//i'm not sure why i was receiving a "\" character cathing file name, but this will control that
while (state.buffer[cont] != 0x0a && cont < StateObject.BufferSize)
    cont++;

string inc_file_name = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, cont);

FileStream Fs = new FileStream(inc_file_name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

int read_cont;
byte [] read_buffer = new byte [1024];

//till end of incoming file
while ((read_cont = handler.Receive(read_buffer)) > 0)
    Fs.Write(read_buffer, 0, read_cont);

//save file
Fs.Close();
```

I hope it helps you.
Thanks for the comments and for your help.

Comment: What's up with the compare to zero loop? Why is that needed? Are you trying to find out where the data received ends?

Comment: Your code seems to assume that the buffer was full. Shouldn't you be passing bytesRead into handler.Receive? Also: it seems to assume that reads === writes (for packets); that is very rarely the case. It also assumes you aren't reusing buffers etc - meaning the zero test is very unreliable.

Comment: Code updated. Now it works fine, you where right about the zero loop, it must be checked with the Receive func.